# A question about defining the structure sheaf of Spec $R$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Pg 76 of Gathmann's Algebraic Geometry [notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf) says the following:

> But in the case of a general affine scheme Spec $R$ the various local rings $R_p$ for $p\in$ Spec $R$ do not lie in some big space, so we cannot just take their intersection.

Don't all the local rings lie in the function field of $R$?

Comment: If $Spec(R)$ isn't an integral scheme this could be problematic.

Comment: If $R$ is an integral domain, then we could form its fraction field and all the local rings $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ would sit inside it. But $R$ isn't necessarily an integral domain -- and if $R$ has a zero divisor then it actually cannot sit inside any field at all.

Answer (score 2):

Any ring with a zero divisor cannot be a subring of a field.

Furthermore, localization at a prime ideal is not always monic. For example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}  / 6 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p} = 3 R$, then $R_\mathfrak{p} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$; the element $3$ is in the kernel of $R \to R_\mathfrak{p}$. ($\frac{3}{1} = \frac{0}{1}$ because $2 \notin \mathfrak{p}$ and $2 (3 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 0) = 0$)

Comment: What is the meaning of "localization at a prime ideal is not always monic"? You mean the natural map $R \longrightarrow R_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is not injective, I guess (from your given example).

Comment: @Krish: Correct.

Comment: @Krish Monic for [monomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism), epic for [epimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism).

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thanks. I missed the terminology.